# Calling Javascript function when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a JS function that I want to execute when a button is clicked. It's basically a search box, which when the button is clicked, will take the inputted text (a postcode) from the input field, and pass it to a PHP script which will convert it to a lat/long using an API, and then output a pin on an embedded Google map. I have done all the PHP/API/Map stuff, and it all works a treat with a hard-coded postcode, but I now need the postcode to be pulled from the search box.

See code below:

**Javascript:**

```
var post_search = document.getElementById('post_search');
function useValue() {
    var postcode = post_search.value;
    // use it
    alert(postcode); // just to show the new value & ensure this portion is working
}
post_search.onchange = useValue;  
post_search.onblur = useValue;
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="post_search_container">
        <input type="text" id="post_search" name="item" placeholder="Search.."/>
        <input type="button" id="nested_search" value="Search.."/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/post_search.js"></script>
    </div>
```

I have read that I can use another "getElementByID" for the button which will then execute the code, but cannot figure out how it works. I have also read that an OnClick event is required, but again, cannot figure that out either. It is also worth mentioning that I do have jQuery (v2.1.3), so if required, I can implement a jQuery method of achieving the above.

Any help is massively appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can with [jquery .click() method](https://api.jquery.com/click/) make : $("#nested_search").click(useValue);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var button = document.getElementById('nested_search');
button.onclick = useValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in jquery, then you can do it by:

```
 $("#buttonId").click(function() {
     //get input text and process
 });
```

or,

```
$("#buttonId").on("click", function() {
    //get input text and process
});
```

In JavaScript:

```
var buttonReference = document.getElementById('nested_search');
buttonReference.onclick = function() {
    //do processing
}
```